# Fetching Spring Cloud Config Server before context starts

Tags: spring-aop, spring-cloud-config

I've got a Spring Boot application that uses `AOP` rules. These rules depend on `application properties`.

Now I have to make this application use `Spring Cloud Config Server`. But the problem is - AOP rules demand properties **before** my application fetches configuration from the Config Server. Is there any way to fetch properties from the server before AOP rules are being resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Did you put `Spring Cloud Config` server properties in `bootstrap.properties` or `bootstrap.yml`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I mean properties necessary to connect to `Spring Cloud Config` server are specified in `bootstrap.yml`.